# Programatically make the index.html from a React project to include the version number from package.json

Tags: reactjs, webpack

The problem I am trying to solve when I deploy a new build, the users need to get the latest `bundle.js` and `bundle.css`, not the browser cached one. The solution the problem is appending a query string to the filename like `/client.bundle.js?v=1.01`. The `1.01` comes from the `package.json`'s `version` property.

The content of the `index.html`, which is contained in the public folder  is below. How do I configure the webpack to modify the index.html automatically when building?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Loading...</title>
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/client.bundle.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

In Webpack build system you can use something like this:

```
const VERSION = JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version)
```

And make this available on window object via Webpack's DefinePlugin

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({__VERSION : VERSION})
```

Which you can use later in index.html file or if you use any templating language.